# Autocomplete com SelectEvent retorna objeto null

Tags: java, primefaces

Estou usando o `autocomplete` e quando insiro um campo, ele preenche sozinho outros dois campos com o método `handleSelect(SelectEvent event)`. Porém esses dois objetos desses campos estão ficando null na hora de gravar. Eu debuguei e vi que eles estão preenchidos, mas na hora de gravar ficam null. E na stacktrace mostra que o atributo `aluno_id` está nulo e não pode persistir, que Aluno é justamente uma das tabelas que será persistida quando for gravar.

**O `autocomplete`**

```
<p:outputLabel value="Título da Monografia: " for="tituloMonografia" />
                <p:autoComplete id="tituloMonografia" size="100"
                    value="#{gestaoBancaDefesaBean.bancaDefesa.monografia}"
                    completeMethod="#{gestaoBancaDefesaBean.completarMonografia}"
                    var="monografia" itemLabel="#{monografia.titulo}"
                    itemValue="#{monografia}" forceSelection="true" groupBy="titulo" >
                    <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{gestaoBancaDefesaBean.listaMonografias}" />
                    <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
                        listener="#{gestaoBancaDefesaBean.handleSelect}"
                        update="aluno" />
                    <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
                        listener="#{gestaoBancaDefesaBean.handleSelect}" update="orientador" />
                </p:autoComplete>
```

**EDIT**

A parte do formulário de Aluno, a entidade que está com problema para persistir

```
<p:outputLabel value="Aluno: " for="aluno" />
                <p:autoComplete id="aluno" size="40"
                    value="#{gestaoBancaDefesaBean.bancaDefesa.monografia.aluno}"                   
                    converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" var="aluno"
                    itemLabel="#{aluno.pessoa.nome}" itemValue="#{aluno}">
                </p:autoComplete>
```

**O método `handleSelect`**

```
 public void handleSelect(SelectEvent event) {

    this.monografia = (Monografia) event.getObject();

}
```

> ```
> abr 01, 2018 7:04:21 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
> WARN: SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
> abr 01, 2018 7:04:21 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
> ERROR: Column 'aluno_id' cannot be null
> abr 01, 2018 7:04:21 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
> ADVERTÊNCIA: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
> javax.el.ELException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:260)
>     at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
>     at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>     at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:150)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:96)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:839)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:870)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1418)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
>
>  Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>     at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:875)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:844)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:849)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.AbstractBeanInstance.invoke(AbstractBeanInstance.java:38)
>     at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
>     at org.jboss.weldx.persistence.EntityManager$2128648003$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.merge(Unknown Source)
>     at com.daniel.monografia.repository.BancaDefesas.guardar(BancaDefesas.java:48)
>     at com.daniel.monografia.service.CadastroBancaDefesaService.salvar(CadastroBancaDefesaService.java:21)
>     at com.daniel.monografia.service.CadastroBancaDefesaService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.salvar$$super(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:49)
>     at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:77)
>     at com.daniel.monografia.util.TransacionalInterceptor.invoke(TransacionalInterceptor.java:42)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:73)
>     at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeAroundInvoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:84)
>     at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:72)
>     at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:56)
>     at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:79)
>     at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:68)
>     at com.daniel.monografia.service.CadastroBancaDefesaService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.salvar(Unknown Source)
>     at com.daniel.monografia.controller.GestaoBancaDefesaBean.salvar(GestaoBancaDefesaBean.java:96)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
>     ... 35 more
> **Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement**
>     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
>     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
>     at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
>     at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2840)
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3411)
>     at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:623)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:277)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:258)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:303)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaMergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaMergeEventListener.java:56)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:235)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:173)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:863)
>     ... 71 more
> **Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'aluno_id' cannot be null**
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>     ... 90 more
> ```

O Bean

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class GestaoBancaDefesaBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private BancaDefesas bancaDefesas;

@Inject
private Professores professores;

@Inject
private Monografias monografias;

@Inject
private FacesMessages messages;

@Inject
private CadastroBancaDefesaService cadastroBancaDefesaService;

private Converter monografiaConverter;

private List<BancaDefesa> listaBancaDefesas;

private List<Professor> listaProfessores;

private List<Monografia> listaMonografias;

private String termoPesquisa;

private BancaDefesa bancaDefesa;

private Aluno aluno;

private Professor professor;

private Monografia monografia;

public void handleSelect(SelectEvent event) {

    this.monografia = (Monografia) event.getObject();

}

@PostConstruct
private void iniciar() {

    bancaDefesa = new BancaDefesa();
    this.bancaDefesa.setMonografia(new Monografia());

    aluno = new Aluno();
    this.aluno.setPessoa(new Pessoa());

    professor = new Professor();
    this.professor.setPessoa(new Pessoa());

    listaProfessores = professores.todos();

    listaMonografias = monografias.todas();
}

public void prepararNovaBanca() {
    //bancaDefesa = new BancaDefesa();
    //this.bancaDefesa.setMonografia(new Monografia());
}

public void prepararEdicao() {

}

public void salvar() {
    cadastroBancaDefesaService.salvar(bancaDefesa);

    atualizarRegistros();

    messages.info("Banca salva com sucesso!");

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(Arrays.asList("frm:bancaDefesasDataTable", "frm:messages"));
}

public void pesquisar() {
    listaBancaDefesas = bancaDefesas.pesquisar(termoPesquisa);

    if (listaBancaDefesas.isEmpty()) {
        messages.info("Sua consulta não retornou registros.");
    }
}

public void todasBancaDefesas() {
    listaBancaDefesas = bancaDefesas.todas();
}

public List<Monografia> completarMonografia(String termo) {
    List<Monografia> listaMonografias = monografias.pesquisar(termo);

 monografiaConverter = new MonografiaConverter(listaMonografias);

    return listaMonografias;
 }

private void atualizarRegistros() {
    if (jaHouvePesquisa()) {
        pesquisar();
    } else {
        todasBancaDefesas();
    }
}

private boolean jaHouvePesquisa() {
    return termoPesquisa != null && !"".equals(termoPesquisa);
}

public String getTermoPesquisa() {
    return termoPesquisa;
}

public void setTermoPesquisa(String termoPesquisa) {
    this.termoPesquisa = termoPesquisa;
}

public List<BancaDefesa> getListaBancaDefesas() {
    return listaBancaDefesas;
}

public void setListaBancaDefesas(List<BancaDefesa> listaBancaDefesas) {
    this.listaBancaDefesas = listaBancaDefesas;
}

public List<Professor> getListaProfessores() {
    return listaProfessores;
}

public void setListaProfessores(List<Professor> listaProfessores) {
    this.listaProfessores = listaProfessores;
}

public List<Monografia> getListaMonografias() {
    return listaMonografias;
}

public void setListaMonografias(List<Monografia> listaMonografias) {
    this.listaMonografias = listaMonografias;
}

public BancaDefesa getBancaDefesa() {
    return bancaDefesa;
}

public void setBancaDefesa(BancaDefesa bancaDefesa) {
    this.bancaDefesa = bancaDefesa;
}

public Monografia getMonografia() {
    return monografia;
}

public void setMonografia(Monografia monografia) {
    this.monografia = monografia;
}

public Converter getMonografiaConverter() {
    return monografiaConverter;
}

public boolean isBancaDefesaSeleciona() {
    return bancaDefesa != null && bancaDefesa.getId() != null;
 }
}
```

A entidade que faz a persistência `BancaDefesa.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="banca_defesa")
public class BancaDefesa implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Future
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "data_defesa")
private Date dataDefesa;

private String local;

private boolean defendida;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "aluno_id")
private Aluno aluno;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="bancadefesa_professor", joinColumns=
{@JoinColumn(name="banca_defesa_id")}, inverseJoinColumns=
{@JoinColumn(name="professor_id")})
private List <Professor> listaProfessores;

@NotNull
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "monografia_id")
private Monografia monografia;

@Transient
private Professor professor;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public boolean isDefendida() {
    return defendida;
}

public void setDefendida(boolean defendida) {
    this.defendida = defendida;
}

public String getLocal() {
    return local;
}

public void setLocal(String local) {
    this.local = local;
}

public Date getDataDefesa() {
    return dataDefesa;
}

public void setDataDefesa(Date dataDefesa) {
    this.dataDefesa = dataDefesa;
}

public Aluno getAluno() {
    return aluno;
}

public void setAluno(Aluno aluno) {
    this.aluno = aluno;
}

public List<Professor> getListaProfessores() {
    return listaProfessores;
}

public void setListaProfessores(List<Professor> listaProfessores) {
    this.listaProfessores = listaProfessores;
}

public Monografia getMonografia() {
    return monografia;
}

public void setMonografia(Monografia monografia) {
    this.monografia = monografia;
}

public Professor getProfessor() {
    return professor;
}

public void setProfessor(Professor professor) {
    this.professor = professor;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    BancaDefesa other = (BancaDefesa) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "BancaDefesa [id=" + id + "]";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olhando o stacktrace do seu problema foi possível observar que a entidade `Aluno` é referenciada na entidade `BancaDefesas`. Como você não incluiu as classes referentes ao seu back-end, acredito que o seu problema esteja em tentar persistir a entidade `BancaDefesas` que faz referência a um objeto `Aluno` que ainda não foi persistido, conforme é mostrado por esse trecho do seu stacktrace:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
...
at com.daniel.monografia.repository.BancaDefesas.guardar(BancaDefesas.java:48)
at com.daniel.monografia.service.CadastroBancaDefesaService.salvar(CadastroBancaDefesaService.java:21)
at com.daniel.monografia.service.CadastroBancaDefesaService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.salvar$$super(Unknown Source)
```

Uma das soluções para esse cenário seria de persistir a entidade `Aluno` antes de persistir a entidade `BancaDefesas`. Como você está utilizando o Hibernate em seu projeto, seria uma boa dar uma olhada na annotation [`CascadeType`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html) do framework em questão.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada e te falo o resultado

Comment: Postei o `Bean` e a `Entity` que estão usadas na persistência. Eu já uso a anotação `CascadeType`, então acho que não é o problema.

Desconfio que seja essa parte do código, pois o objeto `dataDefesa` está recebendo o objeto `monografia`, que recebe o objeto `aluno`, que recebe o objeto `pessoa`, que recebe o atributo `nome`
  `value="#{gestaoBancaDefesaBean.bancaDefesa.monografia.aluno}"                   
                    converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" var="aluno"
                    itemLabel="#{aluno.pessoa.nome}" itemValue="#{aluno}" `

Comment: Veja que existe referência tanto para `Monografia` quanto a `Aluno` no seu mapeamento da classe `BancaDefesa` e no trecho de código que você incluiu acima, é feita a instanciação do aluno no objeto `Monografia`. Talvez a tabela `banca_defesa` não esteja aceitando um valor `null` na coluna `aluno_id`. Faça essa checagem e poste o resultado. Caso fique com dúvida, poste a estrutura da tabela `banca_defesa`.

Comment: Pelo oque entendi, estou errando no relacionamento? Isso oque você falou está certo, a tabela `BancaDefesa` tem os campos `aluno_id` e `professor_id`, como tem na na tabela Monografia

Comment: Foi isso mesmo que você falou, estava relacionando `aluno` e `professor ` tanto com a tabela `monografia`, tanto com a `bancadefesa`. Deixei o relacionamento somente em `monografia` e consegui gravar os dados. Desculpa pela dúvida boba de iniciante, muito obrigado, me ajudou no meu TCC.

Comment: Se conseguiu resolver o seu problema com as informações constantes na resposta, você pode aceitá-la.

Comment: Mas como sua primeira resposta não foi a solução e sim o outro comentário que você me respondeu aqui, como faço? Ou  poso criar uma resposta e marcar como solução?

Comment: Se a resposta está nos comentários da resposta, você pode aceitá-la.